# Is there any possibility to migrate translations from Drupal 5 based project to Drupal 7 project?

Tags: migrations, i18n-l10n

I have a legacy Drupal 5 project which is currently moved to a newer Drupal 7 platform, but the old project also contains a lot of custom translation sets. So I am wondering if there is any possibility to migrate those translations to the new project?

Comment: I can't find it now, but doesn't Drupal [tag:5] have translate/export just like Drupal [tag:6] and [tag:7] do? If [tag:5] can export .po files, [tag:7] will be able to import them. `t()` exists since [tag:4], so I would guess .po export in [tag:5] is plausible.

Comment: OK, thx @Molot! I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: If it is the case, please post self-answer. My comment was just a guess, you are the one who is doing the real work. Oh, and if it is **not** true, edit your question to mention you have looked, and it is not the way. Possibly with screenshots or something :)

Comment: Thank you very much @Molot for your tip with .po files! +100 points to you karma :) Actually there is also translations export form in Drupal 5 under the "admin/settings/locale/language/export" menu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** There is a build-in possibility to export translation strings for each language into .po files in Drupal 5 projects as well. Export form is available under the "admin/settings/locale/language/export" admin menu.